# Delphi - Show modal report with Crystal Reports

Tags: delphi, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 7 and Delphi 7 and wondering how to open a modal preview of the report.

```
Crpe1.Execute;
```

opens a non modal form, but I can't find a way to open a modal one...
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's a long time that i didn't work with TCrpe and Delphi7.

I think that you can change the Tcrpe.Output:= toWindow for a preview and Tcrpe.Output:= toPrinter to print direct to the printer.

I don't know exactly because i don't have delphi7 and Tcrpe on my pc.

Use crpe1.show, then you have also preview dialog.

Comment: Hi Ravaut. I've set Tcrpe.Output to toWindow, but the window shown ist not a modal one. Also crpe1.show gives me a non-modal window.

Comment: If you want to make a showmodal then create a form (TfrmView). Set this form in crpe.windowparent:= (TfrmView)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this example help you to have a showmodal

```
 procedure Tform1.BtnShowViewerClick(Sender: TObject);
 var
   oForm: TForm;
 begin
   oForm:= TForm.Create(Nil);
   try
     oForm.bordericons:= [bisystemmenu]; 
     oForm.OnResize:= OnCrpeViewerResize; 
     crpe1.WindowParent:= oForm;
     crpe1.Show;
     oForm.ShowModal;
   finally
     FreeAndNil(oForm);
   end;
 end;


 procedure TForm1.OnCrpeViewerResize(Sender: TObject);
 begin
   if (sender is TForm) then
   begin
     SetWindowPos(Crpe1.ReportWindowHandle, 
                  HWND_TOP, 
                  0, 
                  0, 
                  TForm(Sender).ClientWidth,
                  TForm(Sender).ClientHeight, 
                  SWP_NOZORDER);     
   end;
 end;
```